# Unwanted Footer while Printing in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2011

Every time I print on my mac (10.8) using Microsoft Word 2011, there is a line at the very bottom in super small font saying like:

(my username) Wednesday, September 5, 2012 3:42:49 PM (timezone)

It doesn't appear on the document, only when I print or export it. How can I remove it?

Comment: Does it do this for every document, or just one specific one?  What about print jobs from other applications?

Comment: every document I do and only from other microsoft applications

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?